# Extending view group gives childcount 0?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am extending a frame layout

and when in the constructor (after it loaded the view from xml) i call getChildCount()

I get 0. How to fix this ?

```
public class DisabledFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {


    public DisabledFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null,0);
    }

    public DisabledFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context,attrs,defStyle);
    }

    public DisabledFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context,attrs,0);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DisabledFrameLayout, 0, 0);


        if(a.hasValue(R.styleable.DisabledFrameLayout_disable_descendants)) {
            boolean disable = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.DisabledFrameLayout_disable_descendants, false);
            if(disable) {
                disableDescendants(this);
            }
        }
        a.recycle();
    }


    private void disableDescendants(ViewGroup v) {
        for (int i=0; i<v.getChildCount();i++) {
            if(v.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup) {
                disableDescendants((ViewGroup)v.getChildAt(i));
            }

            v.setEnabled(false);
            v.setFocusable(false);
            v.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        }
    }


}
```

xml

```
<com.lenabru.DisabledFrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:disable_descendants="true"
             >

            <include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                layout="@layout/fragment_p" />
        </com.lenabru.DisabledFrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In state of constructing your `FrameLayout`, children are still not fully attached to the view. So, calling `getChildCount()` will return you 0.

If you want to iterate over child views and update them, do it inside `onLayout()` or `onMeasure()`.

Refs:

- http://blog.denevell.org/android-custom-views-onlayout-onmeasure.html
- ViewGroup - check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) example code.

Comment: I want to initialise certain number of objects based on the value of childCount. If I do this in onMeasure/onLayout, I get the warning to avoid object allocations in draw/layout operations. What should I do?